# Error with newly created Blog sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, my-site, blog

We are running SharePoint 2013 Server on prems. I am trying to create a new blog site under my personal site. There is a link in the quick lunch but when I click on it, it points me to:

https://[domain]/personal/[username]/Blog/ **_layouts/15/start.aspx#/** default.aspx

the result is to get an error message:
[image]

Instead, if I try to visit the url:
https://[domain]/personal/[username]/Blog/default.aspx

The Blog is showing just fine with a sample post. I am trying to understand why this is happening as there are many users complaining that their link is broken and they cannot access their blog. This is not true on sites with blogs that have posts already.

It seems that when you create a new My site the blog site link is created as well (link is added in the quick launch) but it's not initiated. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because of the Minimal download strategy feature. To fix this:

1. I deactivated the Minimal download strategy feature in the Blog Site
2. Activated the Team Collaboration Lists in the Blog Site.